# Combining two SQL statements with same stem but different where clause

Tags: sql, select, count

Please assist me to combine the following two SQL statements:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS total_number_of_followups_scheduled
FROM PROMIS_LT;
```

and :

```
SELECT Count(Status) AS number_followups_completed,  
FROM PROMIS_LT
WHERE (Status = "Completed");
```

This is what I have but it is not working :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) As total_number_followups_scheduled, 
COUNT(Status) 
FROM (SELECT 
CASE WHEN (Status = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As number_followups_completed FROM PROMIS_LT)
PROMIS_LT;
```

Comment: I'd place that `CASE WHEN` in the SELECT section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the `case` expression **inside** the second `count` call and use the fact that `count` (and many similar aggregate functions) skips `null`s:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_number_of_followups_scheduled,
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Completed' THEN 1 END) AS number_followups_completed
FROM   promis_lt
```